# How should I read this regex pattern of bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to ask about read the regex pattern. I have a regex pattern

```
"/^[ \t]*\/\*<O$firstline>\*\//,/^[ \t]*\/\*<\/O$firstline>\*\//s/\/\///g" $Path/DebugVersion.c
```

How should I read this pattern? I need an explanation about this regex. If anyone can explain this to me you can reply this questions. I'm thankful if you answer this question.

Regard,
Gustina M.S

Comment: What do you know already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually looks like a `sed` expression, and it consists of two regular expressions expressing a range, and another regular expression in a search/replace command.  The basic structure of the command is:

```
/START_EXPRESSION/,/END_EXPRESSION/ COMMAND
```

Where `START_EXPRESSION` and `END_EXPRESSION` are both regular expressions, and `COMMAND_EXPRESSION` is a `sed` command that will execute for every line in between those two expressions (inclusive).

Just to make it clear, the range expression is:

```
/^[ \t]*\/\*<O$firstline>\*\//,/^[ \t]*\/\*<\/O$firstline>\*\//
```

Or, splitting that up a little more:

- `START_EXPRESSION`: /^[ \t]*/**//
- `END_EXPRESSION`: /^[ \t]*/*</O$firstline>*//

And `COMMAND` is `s/\/\///g`.

The link that a commenter provided to https://regex101.com/ should help you understand the individual patterns, and the `sed` man page will also be a useful resource.

Comment: I have searched in https://regex101.com/ and i haven't found the meaning of symbols like "s" and "g". But the other regex I have found it. Can you explain to me about the command part or can you give me any references about it? Thank you before

Comment: [The `sed` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html)